# Kotlin generic factory dynamic cast

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting, factory

I want to create factory of objects with generic parameter:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    fun buzz(param: T)
}
```

I have two implementations for tests:

```
class FooImpl1 : Foo<String> {
    override fun buzz(param: String) {
        // implementation 1
    }
}

class FooImpl2 : Foo<Int> {
    override fun buzz(param: Int) {
        // implementation 2
    }
}
```

Now I have created map to contain all my implementations

```
val implementationMap = mapOf<String, Foo<*>>(
    Pair(firstKey, FooImpl1()),
    Pair(secKey, FooImpl2())
)
```

also I have map with params:

```
val paramMap = mapOf<String, Any>(
    Pair(firstKey, "String param"),
    Pair(secKey, 12)
)
```

but now when I fetch first element from my map:

```
implementationMap.getValue(firstKey).buzz(paramMap.getValue(firstKey))
```

my `buzz` method rejects any param (wants `Nothing` as type)

So I have created another map with types

```
val classMap = mapOf<String, KClass<*>>(
    Pair(firstKey, FooImpl1::class),
    Pair(secKey, FooImpl2::class)
)

val paramClassMap = mapOf<String, KClass<*>>(
    Pair(firstKey, String::class),
    Pair(secKey, Int::class)
)
```

But I cannot cast it like that:

```
implementationMap.getValue(firstKey)
    .cast < classMap.getValue(firstKey) > () // not possible
    .buzz(
        paramMap.getValue(firstKey)
        .cast < paramClassMap.getValue(firstKey) > () // not possible
    )
```

or that

```
(implementationMap.getValue(firstKey) // FooImpl1
    /*not possible */ as classMap.getValue(firstKey)) // (FooImpl1::class)
    .buzz(
        paramMap.getValue(firstKey) // String
        /*not possible */ as paramClassMap.getValue(firstKey)) // (String::class)
```

I also tried to use `Token` type but it does not help eather:

```
val classMap = mapOf<String, Type>(
    Pair(firstKey, object: TypeToken<FooImpl1>() {}.type),
    Pair(secKey, object: TypeToken<FooImpl1>() {}.type)
)
```

Any ideas how to cast it properly? Or some "different approach" ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do some unchecked casting I am afraid.

```
interface Foo<T> {
    fun buzz(param: T)
}

class FooImpl1 : Foo<String> {
    override fun buzz(param: String) {
        println(param)
    }
}

class FooImpl2 : Foo<Int> {
    override fun buzz(param: Int) {
        println(param)
    }
}

val implementationMap = mapOf<String, Foo<*>>(
        Pair("firstKey", FooImpl1()),
        Pair("secKey", FooImpl2())
)

val paramMap = mapOf<String, Any>(
        Pair("firstKey", "String param"),
        Pair("secKey", 12)
)


fun main() {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val imp = implementationMap["firstKey"] as Foo<Any?>
    val param = paramMap["firstKey"]
    imp.buzz(param)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can group them together...

```
class FooWithParam<T>(foo: Foo<T>, param: T) {
    fun doBuzz() = foo.buzz(param)
}

val fooWithParamMap = mapOf<String, FooWithParam<*>>(
    Pair(firstKey, FooWithParam(FooImpl1(), "String param"),
    Pair(secKey, FooWithParam(FooImpl2(), 12))
)

implementationMap[firstKey].doBuzz()
```